# Xarray - InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: indexing, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to extract time series for a variable at a given location in my netcdf dataset. But, I am getting the following error :

```
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b6afb8b627fc> in <module>
----> 1 streamflow = routedat2['Streamflow_tavg'].sel(lat = 37.75, lon = 97.75, method = 'nearest')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py in sel(self, indexers, method, tolerance, drop, **indexers_kwargs)
   1059             method=method,
   1060             tolerance=tolerance,
-> 1061             **indexers_kwargs,
   1062         )
   1063         return self._from_temp_dataset(ds)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in sel(self, indexers, method, tolerance, drop, **indexers_kwargs)
   2064         indexers = either_dict_or_kwargs(indexers, indexers_kwargs, "sel")
   2065         pos_indexers, new_indexes = remap_label_indexers(
-> 2066             self, indexers=indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance
   2067         )
   2068         result = self.isel(indexers=pos_indexers, drop=drop)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/coordinates.py in remap_label_indexers(obj, indexers, method, tolerance, **indexers_kwargs)
    395 
    396     pos_indexers, new_indexes = indexing.remap_label_indexers(
--> 397         obj, v_indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance
    398     )
    399     # attach indexer's coordinate to pos_indexers

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in remap_label_indexers(data_obj, indexers, method, tolerance)
    268             coords_dtype = data_obj.coords[dim].dtype
    269             label = maybe_cast_to_coords_dtype(label, coords_dtype)
--> 270             idxr, new_idx = convert_label_indexer(index, label, dim, method, tolerance)
    271             pos_indexers[dim] = idxr
    272             if new_idx is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in convert_label_indexer(index, label, index_name, method, tolerance)
    188             else:
    189                 indexer = index.get_loc(
--> 190                     label.item(), method=method, tolerance=tolerance
    191                 )
    192         elif label.dtype.kind == "b":

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    506         except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
    507             pass
--> 508         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    509 
    510     @cache_readonly

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2647             except KeyError:
   2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
-> 2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
   2651             raise TypeError("get_loc requires scalar valued input")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2732         if not self.is_unique:
   2733             raise InvalidIndexError(
-> 2734                 "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
   2735             )
   2736 
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

My xarray dataset looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onxi2.png)

I am on Xarray 0.15.1 within conda environment.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT :
As per suggestions, I was able to surpass InvalidIndex error by correcting the lats and longs.
The current xarray looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7rjI.jpg)

But, now I am getting following error while executing

`streamflow = routedat2['Streamflow_tavg'].sel(lat = 5.75 , lon = 97.75, method = 'nearest')` :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in remap_label_indexers(data_obj, indexers, method, tolerance)
    256         try:
--> 257             index = data_obj.indexes[dim]
    258         except KeyError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexes.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     58     def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 59         return self._indexes[key]
     60 

KeyError: 'lat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-9faf7a9fa8c4> in <module>
----> 1 streamflow = routedat2['Streamflow_tavg'].sel(lat = 5.75 , lon = 97.75, method = 'nearest')
      2 print(streamflow.values)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py in sel(self, indexers, method, tolerance, drop, **indexers_kwargs)
   1059             method=method,
   1060             tolerance=tolerance,
-> 1061             **indexers_kwargs,
   1062         )
   1063         return self._from_temp_dataset(ds)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in sel(self, indexers, method, tolerance, drop, **indexers_kwargs)
   2064         indexers = either_dict_or_kwargs(indexers, indexers_kwargs, "sel")
   2065         pos_indexers, new_indexes = remap_label_indexers(
-> 2066             self, indexers=indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance
   2067         )
   2068         result = self.isel(indexers=pos_indexers, drop=drop)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/coordinates.py in remap_label_indexers(obj, indexers, method, tolerance, **indexers_kwargs)
    395 
    396     pos_indexers, new_indexes = indexing.remap_label_indexers(
--> 397         obj, v_indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance
    398     )
    399     # attach indexer's coordinate to pos_indexers

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py in remap_label_indexers(data_obj, indexers, method, tolerance)
    260             if method is not None or tolerance is not None:
    261                 raise ValueError(
--> 262                     "cannot supply ``method`` or ``tolerance`` "
    263                     "when the indexed dimension does not have "
    264                     "an associated coordinate."

ValueError: cannot supply ``method`` or ``tolerance`` when the indexed dimension does not have an associated coordinate.`
```

Comment: Please add the code used that resulted in the error.

Comment: Hi @RobertWilson, here's the code which results in this error : 
`streamflow = routedat2['Streamflow_tavg'].sel(lat = 37.75, lon = 97.75, method = 'nearest')`

Comment: Thanks. This is most likely a data issue causes by having repeated nan values for coordinates. This would explain the "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" error when you are interpolating. Try removing or replacing the nan values

Comment: Thank you. You suggestion worked but now I am facing a new error. Please check the EDIT section in the original post. Thanks

Comment: Have the coordinates been dropped? Please add what the xarray object looks like after fixing the lat/lon

Comment: It still has the same dimensions, I basically refereed another netcdf file of the same scale and area to get lat lon. I will add it nonetheless.

Comment: This is not a helpful question as it's just a dump of error messages and data inputs with little evidence of any effort to identify the minimal cause of the issue. As such, it is difficult for other users to identify what the general problem is and how it may or may not apply to their specific situation.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Seems like the issue was somewhere in how I was extracting the lats and longs in first place. Got it resolved now.

Comment: This is not a useful answer as it provides no details about how the problem was resolved that others can use to solve similar problems.